# Plot in order ggplot - R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I have a `dataframe` in long format ready to use with `ggplot`. It has 3 variables: ID (1:10), image (1:24) and values (some indexes). Here is the head:

```
    ID image         value
1    1     1  0.0408963431
2    2     1  0.1366366334
3    3     1  0.1250891286
4    4     1  0.6980148222
5    5     1  0.1537595064
6    6     1  0.6088030843
7    7     1  0.1618058842
8    8     1  0.0007617827
9    9     1 -0.0098789526
10  10     1  0.7994192766
11   1     2  0.0326733369
12   2     2  0.0304698831
13   3     2  0.1100861336
14   4     2  0.5145008107
15   5     2  0.1424066920
16   6     2  0.6982905393
17   7     2  0.2033906321
18   8     2  0.0506560177
19   9     2  0.0223501625
20  10     2  0.8014009445
```

So far I am using:

`ggplot(NDVIdfmean_forplot, aes(x = image, y= value, group = ID)) + geom_line()`

to plot my `dataframe`. Although the code does the job, the order of the x axes is not correct. Here is the image

[Plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d93bl.png)

As you can see the order is 1, 10, 11, 12 ... 19, 2, 20, 21 ... I would like to plot my data in ascending order, so: 1,2,3,4,etc.

I have been trying to order my data properly

`ggplot(NDVIdfmean_forplot[order(NDVIdfmean_forplot$image),], aes(x=image, y=value, group=ID)) + geom_line() +
  geom_path()`

But I haven't manage to solve it. The same output is produced.

Any idea on that?

Comment: Could give us a reproducible example with `dput()` or is your dataset really large? I wasn't able to reproduce your problem with the data shown above.

Comment: Hi @tyluRp, thanks for your comment, I just manage to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two approaches:

Turn column image to numeric:

```
library(ggplot2)

NDVIdfmean_forplot$image <- as.numeric(NDVIdfmean_forplot$image)
ggplot(NDVIdfmean_forplot, aes(image, value, group = ID, color = ID)) + 
    geom_line()
```

Use `scale_x_discrete` with sorted `image` values:

```
ggplot(NDVIdfmean_forplot, aes(image, value, group = ID)) + 
    geom_path() +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(sort(as.numeric(unique(NDVIdfmean_forplot$image)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Works as well. By the way, how can I define specific colors for each ID group in my code?

Comment: I was using this option as well but it applies a blue color ramp. I would like to define my own colors or my own color ramp. Something similar to what you do in regular `plot` with `col=c("orange", "blue", "red") ...`

Comment: check `scale_color_manual` and argument `values`, what you need to do is something like this: `scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue", "red"))`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it, so I'll post the solution in case it helps someone

The problem was that my image variable was not a factor. I used:

`NDVIdfmean_forplot$image <- factor(NDVIdfmean_forplot$image,levels=unique(as.character(NDVIdfmean_forplot$image)) )`

To convert it to factor an order it properly. Now the graph correct